# Why is it causing this error and how can in fix it

Tags: python, list, pygame

Im trying to code Minesweeper on python for a school. I watched a youtube video about that and copied it a little bit. But now im stuck because of this error:

File "e:\Schule\Spiele\Minesweeper\Minesweeper.py", line 98, in loadImages
`self.images[images] = pygame.image.load(images)`
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.

```
import pygame
import os



class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = (9,9)
        self.screenSize = (800, 800)



class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.setBoard()

    def setBoard(self):
        self.board = []
        
        for row in range(self.settings.size[0]):
            row= []

            for col in range(self.settings.size[1]):
                piece = None
                row.append(piece)
            self.board.append(row)

    def getSize(self):
        return self.settings.size


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self) :
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.board = Board()
        self.pieceSize = self.settings.screenSize[0] // self.board.getSize()[1], self.settings.screenSize[1] // self.board.getSize()[0]
        self.loadImages()



    def run(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.settings.screenSize)

        running = True

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    running = False
            self.draw()

            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.quit
```

This is the function that causes the error but i dont know how to fix this.
It should create a grid with that images

```
    def draw(self):
        pass
        topLeft = (0,0)

        for i in range(self.board.getSize()[0]):
            for n in range(self.board.getSize()[1]):
                image =  self.images["norm_zelle.gif"]
                self.screen.blit(image , topLeft)
                topLeft = topLeft[0] + self.pieceSize[0] , topLeft[1]
            topLeft = 0, topLeft[1] + self.pieceSize[1]
            

    def loadImages(self):
        self.images = {}
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(file_path, "images")
        sound_path = os.path.join(file_path, "sounds")

        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOWS_POS'] = "50, 1100"
    pygame.init()
    game = Game()
    game.run()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `norm_zelle.gif`? Also I don't think your `loadImages` method is complete. You don't load your images into `self.images`

Answer (score 2):

Your `loadImages` function is never actually loading the images! Try adding the following code inside of `loadImages`:

```py
for image in image_path:
    self.images[image] = pygame.image.load(image)
```

You will also have to provide a file named `norm_zelle.gif`, which should go in a directory named `images`.

NB: You'll probably want to do the same for sounds.

Comment: thx for helping me

Comment: I'm going to have a hard time working with so little information, I'd recommend you edit the original question or open a new one :)

Comment: ok im gonna do it